# Sending form data in nodejs using https.request

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I am trying to post a request with my nodejs server to another server and then I have to save response in a file. I am using nodejs https.request module.

This is my request:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('first',3);
    formData.append('second', '25');
    formData.append('source_file', fs.createReadStream(sourcefile));
    formData.append('source_image', fs.createReadStream(sourceimage));

var options = {
    hostname: 'ip',
    path: '/api/path',
    method: 'POST'
}
var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.pdf");
var req = https.request(options, (response) => {
    response.pipe(file);
    console.log("File saved");
    response.send("done")
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });

  req.write(formData);
  req.end();
```

But I am getting the error

```
First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

I tried sending my files using `formData.toString()` but on using this, error disappears but My files are not working and also I have sent data like this:

```
 var formData = new FormData();
formData = {
        first: 3,
        second: '25',
        source_file: fs.createReadStream(sourcefile),
        source_image: fs.createReadStream(sourceimage)
    };
```

How can I send my files to other server using this request.

Thanks

Comment: you are not setting up request headers.

Comment: Tried this headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata'
          } din't work. Do I have to send it with toString()?

Comment: Can you add which module you're using to provide `FormData`?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data).
To fix the `First argument must be a string or Buffer` error replace:

```js
req.write(formData);
req.end();
```

with

```
formData.pipe(req);
```

(`formData` behaves like a Node.js [`ReadableStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams))

You should also add headers to your request:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'ip',
    path: '/api/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: formData.getHeaders()
}
```

Source: https://github.com/form-data/form-data#alternative-submission-methods

Comment: `formData.pipe(req);` saved my day. :)

Comment: Node 18+ comes with a native `FormData` object which doesn't have the `.pipe()` or a `.getHeaders()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

I once faced an issue similar to this. I resolved it using the `form-data` package available on NPM [here](http://npmjs.com/package/form-data) with the `axios` package [here](http://npmjs.com/package/axios)

the snippet below worked for me

```
const FormData = require("form-data");
const axios = require("axios");

const form = new FormData();
form.append("first", 3);
// other data should go here
form.append("file", fs.createReadStream("filePath"));

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "url",
  data: form,
  headers: { ...form.getHeaders() }
});
```

Comment: OP is using https.request, not axios

Answer (score 0):

You can use node inbuilt `body-parser` module to parse the form data into JSON and 
you have to use 
`app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`
And when you do `req.body` then it will your form data into an object form.

Comment: can you please provide some code example?